# Using Android Mock location, can one detect location requests and provide locations on the fly?

Tags: java, android, gps, location, android-location

I was wondering, is it possible, using the Mock location permission, to detect location requests like Google maps, and provide it with custom location on the fly, **like a proxy for location**?.

I've managed to get a fixed location using the below code:

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
manager.addTestProvider(customProvider, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5);
manager.setTestProviderEnabled(customProvider, true);

Location mockLocation = new Location(customProvider);
mockLocation.setLongitude(0);
mockLocation.setLatitude(0);
mockLocation.setAltitude(0);
mockLocation.setAccuracy(1);
mockLocation.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
mockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
manager.setTestProviderLocation(customProvider, mockLocation);
```

Is it possible to achieve something more dynamic? If not, would rooting the device help accomplish this task?